# How do I move my integer calculation at mainactivity to the other activity textview?

Tags: java, android

I got a problem on figuring out how to bring over integers calculation from main activity to the other activity by view its text view.

Have tried to put intent methods at the activity 2, but could not link it to the Mainactivity.java

MainActivity

```
else {

                    int P = Integer.parseInt(etPrincipal.getText().toString().trim());
                    int PMT = Integer.parseInt(etRegular.getText().toString().trim());
                    int r = Integer.parseInt(etRate.getText().toString().trim());
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(etTimes.getText().toString().trim());
                    int t = Integer.parseInt(etYears.getText().toString().trim());

                    int calculation = (P *(1 + (r / n) )^(n*t));


                    Intent gotoactivity2 = new Intent( MainActivity.this, com.app.compoundinginterestproject.Activity2.class);
                    gotoactivity2.putExtra("name", calculation);
                    startActivity(gotoactivity2);
                }
```

Activity2

```
  TextView tvone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        tvone = findViewById(R.id.tvone);

        Intent calculate = getIntent(Activity2.this, com.app.compoundinginterestproject.MainActivity.class);
        int calculate = MainActivity.getIntExtra("name", 0")

        tvone.setText(calculate + " is the calculation ");

    }
}
```

I would like to expect the input calculation to the activity2 textview output
but got an error: unclosed string literal

Comment: int calculate = MainActivity.getIntExtra("name", 0") should have 2 or 4 quotes, not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error has nothing to do with the Intent logic for passing the value. It's is a compile time error that's happening because you put one double quote next to the `0` that shouldn't be there

```
int calculate = MainActivity.getIntExtra("name", 0")
```

Remove it so the line now ends up being like the following:

```
int calculate = MainActivity.getIntExtra("name", 0)
```